# How to get the revision from SVN repository between two dates using Groovy Script?

Tags: groovy

I am using Groovy script.

I am trying to write a Groovy script for getting the revisions between two dates
as we are getting the revision on SVN log. I am new to Groovy I tried many ways but failed to success.

Can any one please help me to get this task done.

Comment: please add the code for what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();
String url = "(directory in svn url)";
String name = "(login name)";
String password = "(login password)";
SVNRepository repository = null;
repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(url));
ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager =
                   SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(name, password);
repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
SVNDirEntry entry = repository.info(".", -1);
System.out.println("Latest Rev: " + entry.getRevision());
```

You will need to use the svnkit downloaded from here: http://svnkit.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this code is only gives the latest revision from the repository, but I need the revision between two dates. Can you please guide me for this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you better: http://svnkit.com/kb/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/io/SVNRepository.html#getDatedRevision(java.util.Date)

notice to function:

```
public abstract long getDatedRevision(Date date) SVNException
```

Comment: Thank you again, the above method return the recent revision of the date specified by us. But it is not returning the revision between two date. I have tried this code:

Comment: Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2015, 01, 14);
Date date = cal.getTime();


Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.set(2014, 10, 12);
Date date1 = cal1.getTime();
SVNRevision svr = new SVNRevision(date)
 svr.create(date)
SVNRevision svr1 = new SVNRevision(date1)
 svr1.create(date1)

 
 SVNRevisionRange.getStartRevision()


SVNRevision.(Date new Date(Calendar.g.)
SVNRevisionRange obj = new SVNRevisionRange()
obj.startRevision(04-08-2014)
obj.endRevision(08-01-2015)
But it is also not giving the out put

Comment: try to have some loop using your start and end date, each iteration will take the file you need of the current date in the iteration