# How to Get the revision history between two revision date or number?

Tags: groovy

This is the repetition of my previous question about getting revision history fro SVN repository by using Groovy script. I have tried many way, the code I have tried now is:

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.set(2015, 01, 14);
 Date date = cal.getTime();

 Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal1.set(2014, 10, 12);
 Date date1 = cal1.getTime();

 SVNRevision svr = new SVNRevision(date)
 svr.create(date)
 SVNRevision svr1 = new SVNRevision(date1)
 svr1.create(date1)


 DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();
 String url = "Url"
 String name = "Name";
 String password = "Password";
 SVNRepository repository = null;
 repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(url));
 ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(name, password);
  repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
  SVNDirEntry entry = repository.info(".", -1);


 final long EndRevision = repository.getDatedRevision(date)
 final long StartRevision= repository.getDatedRevision(date1)

 println(latestRevision1)
 println(latestRevision2)

 logEntries = repository.log( { "" } as String[] , null ,StartRevision, EndRevision , true , true );


 for ( Iterator entries = logEntries.iterator( ); entries.hasNext( ); ) {
        SVNLogEntry logEntry = ( SVNLogEntry ) entries.next( );
        System.out.println (String.format("revision: %d, date %s", logEntry.getRevision( ), logEntry.getDate()));
 }
```

But while executing the above code the error is showing as:

```
Caught: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: Path not found 404 not found
```

I am unable to resolve the error, Can any one please tell me what the error is?
and provide me the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the revision from SVN repository between two dates using Groovy Script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977387/how-to-get-the-revision-from-svn-repository-between-two-dates-using-groovy-scrip)

Comment: you stated the duplicate already yourself.  please keep the question on it's own.  the question there already attracted two answers and you even accepted one.  if the code there was not helpful or does not work, then please keep it going there.  or maybe it would be better to rephrase the question and the code there to get to a minimal block of code.  and also provide a stacktrace and annotate the line, where it throws.

Comment: `{ "" } as String[]` might work, but is rather odd (return a string from a closure).  rather use `[""] as String[]`

Comment: Thank you, Yes,  it is working now, Can you explain in detail what the problem with the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `respository.log` with a wrong argument/path.  The code `{ "" } as String[]` works, but is not returning what you are expecting.  Your intention is this:

```
[""] as String[] // a list of strings (one empty string)
```

With the code above you are defining a closure (`{}` is only used for closures in groovy and not for static array (like in java)) and then you cast it to a string list.  The resulting list then is not a list with an empty string, but with the `toString` of the closure.  See:

```
def f = {""} as String[]
print f.inspect()
// => ['c$_run_closure1@3b39132f']
```

And this path most likely, das noth exist in your repo.